# Java regular expression to exclude a word (negative lookaround) between variable length tokens

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

My intention is to discover whether the patient has hypertension or not.

This should match:

> The patient has diabetes, high cholesterol and hypertension.
>
> The patient is positive for diabetes, high cholesterol and hypertension.

This should NOT match:

> The patient has no diabetes, high cholesterol or hypertension.
>
> The patient is known to have no diabetes, high cholesterol or hypertension.

I can use this to match both:

```
patient[^\.]{0,}?hypertension
```

But, this does not work (still matches both) on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ :

```
patient[^\.]{0,}?(?!no)[^\.]{0,}?hypertension
```

So, how can I exclude matches that include "no" between "patient" and "hypertension"?

Please keep in mind that any number of characters might be anywhere between "patient", "no" and "hypertension".

Thanks a lot!!!

P.S.: I know negation finding can be way more complicated than this, but, for my current effort, just identifying words meaning negation should suffice.

Comment: Well it can be done, but regex is not the write tool for this. How are you getting those sentences? Can't you have the information in some other way than plain string?

Comment: Thanks, Rohit. The sentences are buried in long texts describing the patient.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to write a waterproof regex for human language, but the pattern I suggest you can give you an idea of how to proceed:

```
\bpatient\b(?>[^nhi.]++|\B[nhi]|n(?!o\b)|h(?!ypertension\b)|i(?!s\s+negative\s+for\b|sn't\s+known\s+to\s+have\b))+hypertension\b
```

However a sentence with a double negation will make the pattern to fail:

example: `The patient isn't known to have diabetes, but hypertension.`

Comment: Wow, that's a complex Regex. I appreciate your help very much. I think I understand -- you have "hardcoded" the possible combinations. But I need to add plenty of possible negation words besides "no" ("denies", "negative for", "resolved", things like that) so I think this approach is not really what I should look for.

Comment: @user2988800: it isn't so complex, as you can see i forbid the first letter of words or expression i want to avoid `[^nhi.]` and after I allow these letters with a negative lookahead to check if it isn't these expressions. If I have the time, I will add the `(?(DEFINE))` syntax which can be interesting in this kind of situation. (and more readable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead to match one but not the other:

```
(?=(patient.*hypertension))(?!(patient.*no.*hypertension))
```

And like the Rohit & Casimir mentioned, regex is not the right tool for the task: you should build a parser that includes all the options you can thing of (like the "double negative" that Casimir showed for example) and most probably you'll have to update the parser once in a while when you'll run into other possibilities you missed.